# собрать из списка английских слов предложение

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу реализовать данную фичу. Столкнулся с проблемой реализации логики. Текст который надо отгадать сделал из 8 TextView (8 слов в тексте). Сделал onClick сo switch case для 8 кнопок (8 слов-кнопок соответственно). В каждой из них надо реализовать логику. Пытался сделать сравнения с помощью getText для кнопок и для текствьюшек, по типу if (button.getText().toString().equals(textView1.getText().toString())) { тогда первое слово угадано, textView1.setVisibility(Visible) //показывается первое слово, остальные скрыты. далее нужно перейти к сравнению текста с textView2 (второе слово) и так далее }
Проблема в том что это костыль, при таком подходе нужно проверять каждую кнопку на сравнение с каждой TextView. И то не факт что прокатит. Есть ли кто-нибудь кто уже реализовывал данную фичу и мог бы как-то подсказать решение данной проблемы. Может быть кто-то знает какой-нибудь туториал по данной теме. Буду благодарен! (p.s. извиняюсь за такое мучительное объяснение)

Comment: p.s данный скриншот взят из приложения Ewa

Comment: храните список слов в массиве. А сами кнопки тоже или просто один раз напишите функцию преобразования кнопки в ее индекс. Дальше все сильно-сильно упростится

Comment: @KoVadim
String[] words = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.phrase_strings);
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(words));

        button.setText(words[0]);
        button2.setText(words[1]);
...
что значит функция преобразования кнопки в её индекс?

Comment: заведите массив, элементами которого будут button, button2, button3 и так далее. и теперь можно будет просто написать цикл, что бы выставить на всех кнопках текст